# Finding the Reisz Representing Measure of a Positive Linear Functional Involving the Diadic Rationals

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

My problem: "For some continuous monotonically increasing function g define  $\Lambda_n(f)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(\frac{k}{2^n})(g(\frac{k}{2^n})-g(\frac{k-1}{2^n}))$.  Show that each $\Lambda_n$ is a positive linear functional on continuous compact supported functions on the real line $C_c(R)$, show that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Lambda_n=\Lambda$ is a well defined positive linear functional on continuous compact supported functions, find the corresponding measure space $(R,M, \mu)$, and compute the measure of $[0,1]$".

Obviously this is pretty big, and I don't expect anyone to do my homework for me.  My question is, for a continuous compact-supported function on the real line, it will obviously be upper bounded, say by $N$.  Then as n goes to infinity and the set of points becomes finer, the difference $(g(\frac{k}{2^n})-g(\frac{k-1}{2^n}))$ should go to zero and the whole sum be upper bounded by $N \cdot \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (g(\frac{k}{2^n})-g(\frac{k-1}{2^n}))=0$, right?  I feel I should be wrong because then the answer to the rest of the problem is trivial, but I can't see my mistake.

Edit:  I've thought about this problem more and I think I see my problem.  The difference doesn't actually approach zero, and it was just muddled thinking that led me to believe it would be so (finals week).

For a given $n$, we have 
For each $n$, we have $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f(\frac{k}{2^n})(g(\frac{k}{2^n})-g(\frac{k-1}{2^n}))\leq N \cdot \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty (g(\frac{k}{2^n})-g(\frac{k-1}{2^n}))$, which is in fact a telescoping sum, giving $lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (g(\frac{k}{2^n})+g(\frac{-k}{2^n}))$, right?  Does the method for finding the closed form for a telescoping sum work when the sum is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Why should the last sum be zero?

Comment: Because g is continuous, and in the limit as n goes to infinity the difference $g(\frac{k}{2^n})-g(\frac{(k-1)}{2^n})$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about Riemann-stieltjes integral. In fact what you are defining are just Riemann sums of f with respect to g in the support of f, taking as partition the "cubes" of length $1/(2^n)$ contained in the support.